# Find max in columns in pairs of two - pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, max

I would like to find the max in columns in pairs of two

I have the following columns:

```
user_id', 'fullname', 'email', 'handle', 'audience_ethnicities_code0', 'audience_ethnicities_weight0', 'audience_ethnicities_code1', 'audience_ethnicities_weight1', 'audience_ethnicities_code2', 'audience_ethnicities_weight2', 'audience_ethnicities_code3', 'audience_ethnicities_weight3'
```

where code and weigh are related, for example:

==> user_id = ABCD

```
'audience_ethnicities_code0' = asian; 'audience_ethnicities_weight0' = 0.4

'audience_ethnicities_code1' = african; 'audience_ethnicities_weight1' = 0.2

'audience_ethnicities_code2' = white; 'audience_ethnicities_weight2' = 0.2

'audience_ethnicities_code3' = hispanic; 'audience_ethnicities_weight3' = 0.2
```

tot weight = 1, and the audience of user ABCD is 40% Asian, 20% African etc, so for user ABCS Asians are the top audience with 40%

==> user_id = XMYN

```
'audience_ethnicities_code0' = asian; 'audience_ethnicities_weight0' = 0.1

'audience_ethnicities_code1' = hispanic; 'audience_ethnicities_weight1' = 0.7

'audience_ethnicities_code2' = white; 'audience_ethnicities_weight2' = 0.1

'audience_ethnicities_code3' = african; 'audience_ethnicities_weight3' = 0.1
```

so for user XMYN top audience is Hispanics with 70%

NOTE that `'audience_ethnicities_code0'` can be white, african, hispanic, asian. Same thing for `'audience_ethnicities_code1', 'audience_ethnicities_code2', 'audience_ethnicities_code3'`

What I want is to have ethnicity (`audience_ethnicities_code_n` ) in the column and in the row their weight (`audience_ethnicities_weight_n` ) for each user

any ideas?

Comment: Please provide an expected output in form of a DataFrame/table

Comment: Hi Andre, I want to create a new column with the column name that has the highest weight

Answer (score 0):

When I got you right, you can do the following using the above example data:

```
list_dicts = []
for user in df["user_id"].unique():
    list_dicts.append(dict(zip(df[df["user_id"]==user].filter(like="code").values.flatten(), df[df["user_id"]==user].filter(like="weight").values.flatten())))
```

Afterwards just create a DataFrame from this list using `pd.DataFrame(list_dicts)`, add the user column `df_new["user"] = df["user_id"].unique()` and you get

```
    asian   african white   hispanic  user
0   0.4     0.2     0.2     0.2       ABCD
1   0.1     0.1     0.1     0.7       XMYN
```